# Combine the result of two query column-wise without any join condition

Tags: mysql, sql, join

One of my friend at workplace asked me "How to combine the result of two query column-wise without any join condition?"
After googling and trying out myself I couldn't find any solution.

**TableA**

`field1 field2
"abc1" "def1"
"abc2"  "def2"`

**TableB**

`field3 field4
"ghi1"  "jkl1"
"ghi2"  "jkl2"`

The query should result:

`field1 field2  field3  field4
"abc1"  "def1"  "ghi1"  "jkl1"
"abc2"  "def2"  "ghi2"  "jkl2"`

`select "","",* from tableA  union all  select *,"","" from tableB` 
is close but results in 4 rows

All the joins will either cross join or not join because we do not have any field to satisfy join condition.

Comment: What database are you using, MySQL or SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in MySQL using variables:

```
select a.field1, a.field2, b.field3, b.field4
from (select a.*, @rna := @rna + 1 as rn
      from tableA a cross join
           (select @rna := 0) const
     ) a join
     (select b.*, @rnb := @rnb + 1 as rn
      from tableB b cross join
           (select @rnb := 0) const
     ) b
     on a.rn = b.rn;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest row_number(), but it seems that forces you to sort on one of the columns.

Alternatively, you could try cobbling together a result set manually using cursors:

```
declare @result table 
(
  field1 nvarchar(256),
  field2 nvarchar(256),
  field3 nvarchar(256),
  field4 nvarchar(256)
)

declare @cursor1 cursor
for select field1, field2 from TableA
for read only

declare @cursor2 cursor
for select field1, field2 from TableB
for read only

declare @f1 nvarchar(256)
declare @f2 nvarchar(256)
declare @f3 nvarchar(256)
declare @f4 nvarchar(256)

declare @fetchstatus1 int
declare @fetchstatus2 int

open @cursor1
open @cursor2

fetch next from @cursor1 into @f1, @f2
set @fetchstatus1 = @@FETCH_STATUS
fetch next from @cursor2 into @f3, @f4
set @fetchstatus2 = @@FETCH_STATUS
while @fetchstatus1 = 0 && @fetchstatus2 = 0
begin
  insert into @result values(@f1, @f2, @f3, @f4)

  fetch next from @cursor1 into @f1, @f2
  set @fetchstatus1 = @@FETCH_STATUS
  fetch next from @cursor2 into @f3, @f4
  set @fetchstatus2 = @@FETCH_STATUS
end

close @cursor1
close @cursor2
deallocate @cursor1
deallocate @cursor2

select field1, field2, field3, field4
from @result
```

You may be able to sense my procedural programming background coming through here a bit though =P